# Add help text to title D7

Tags: 7, nodes

How can I add Help text to the Title in D7?

Perhaps adding an 'edit' button similar to the other *normal* fields.

Ideally the solution integrates with [Label Help](https://www.drupal.org/project/label_help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'title' on a node is not a field, but a property, you can convert it into a field (with all it's goodness) with https://www.drupal.org/project/title .

Answer (score 2):

This module can be used to add help text to node title
https://www.drupal.org/project/node_title_help_text